# Is it possible to authenticate to htaccess via POST?

Tags: java, php, .htaccess, post

I have put htaccess password in root of my domain. Now i want to authenticate it from my mobile app. Is it possible to handle this or i need a SESSION validation ?

My current index.php is looks like this.

```
<?php

  if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {

      header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
      header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
      echo 'Text to send if user hits Cancel button';
      exit;

  } else {

      echo "<p>Hello {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}.</p>";
      echo "<p>You entered {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']} as your password.</p>";

  }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to handle this with htaccess or PHP? You should do one or the other, not a mixture of both...

Comment: i want to use htaccess in root folder and authenticate it through my blackberry app [POST method]  ?

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't make any sense. And if you are using HTTP auth, the request method has nothing to do with it. What data is your BB app sending to the server?

Comment: My BB app is requesting data from server.

Comment: The situation is, my client added htaccess password in server now i am getting error if i make a request to server. !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some clients still support http://username:password@domain.com/path/script. A proper client supports it but hides the credentials from url history.

Your phone should prompt for a login screen if you enabled htpasswd through htaccess correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try appending the username and password the url:
https://username:password@www.webiste.com/secretfolder/